# Web Development , How to get favicon?

Tags: javascript, html

How to retrieve a *favicon* from any URL?

For example I want to get favicon of *Github* or any other website then I can get favicon with the help of URL only.

Comment: You need to show the code that you've written, and describe exactly what problem you're having.

Comment: This might help:
https://gist.github.com/davidmaxwaterman/aa0368be171249ebe14e59e75468e04b

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
http://www.google.com/s2/favicons?domain=<WEBSITE HERE>
```

It's a small service provided by Google now.
It returns any favicon from a given domain like GitHub if you want.

**Example**
http://www.google.com/s2/favicons?domain=www.github.com

**[Info](http://codingclues.eu/2009/retrieve-the-favicon-for-any-url-thanks-to-google/)**

Answer (score 2):

From *only the URL*?  You'd have to guess.  For example, you might try:

```
http://www.github.com/favicon.ico
```

It's not guaranteed for any given site, but it's a common guess.  But if you can also fetch the HTML from the site, you can look for the `<link rel="icon" ...>` element to see what the page references:

```
<link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="https://assets-cdn.github.com/favicon.ico">
```

Answer (score 1):

GitHub's favicon is at https://assets-cdn.github.com/favicon.ico

The easiest way to look for a favicon is to view the source code of the page once its loaded and look for the  tag.

Answer (score 1):

> For example I want to get favicon of Github or any other website then I can get favicon with the help of URL only.

You

1. Read the HTML of the URL and see if it provides a `link` with a `rel` attribute containing the space-delimited word `icon` (such as `rel="icon"` or `rel="shortcut icon"`).
2. If so, you use the relative URL that link's `href` resolves to. If not, you use `favicon.ico`.
3. Resolve that relative URL against the original URL.
4. Retrieve the image from that URL.

If step 4 fails, you know that the site doesn't have a favicon (or that its HTML is broken). (You might fail back to using `favicon.ico` if the site specified a different path, but...)

Note that you won't be able to do this in a *browser* unless the other origin gives you access to its content via [Cross-Origin Resource Sharing](http://www.w3.org/TR/access-control/). But you can do it from non-browser code.